# Subversion, getting along with messy road-map

Tags: svn, version-control

I am maintaining a large website with many new features every day.
We don't have a clear road map of development features ( Don't ask y /-: ).
My  problem is that every 2 days we need to update the production environment with small features and it is a must thing.

In parallel to that, in the same site we have also a development of large features that its development time can be a week and more.

What is the best way to manage that?
I want to be able to provide small features with large features within the same site, even the same files.

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698313/what-is-trunk-branch-and-tag-in-subversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Develop the large features in independent [branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.html).

The small changes can (presumably) be performed on the repo as normal, then the development branches merged in upon completion.