# SVN checkout doesn't create packages - java

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, package

I'm trying to check out a svn repo. So far so good, the checkout worked but there are no Packages. Is there a way to get the right packages in eclipse?

All the given data I do have is this:

```
svn co https://jensembl.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jensembl jensembl
```

Furthermore, I'll add the link to the program, which i want to get working.
[link to JEnsembl](http://jensembl.sourceforge.net/svn.html)

/edit added a link to the explorer view of the current project
[link](http://oi49.tinypic.com/x6d7n.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you run that command? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: i expect it to become a normal project with all the required packages in eclipse. I also used the eclipse svn plugin with the link. But nothing makes the right packages. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate eclipse project files using Maven.

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html

Basically:

```
$ mvn install
$ mvn -Declipse.workspace=<path-to-eclipse-workspace> eclipse:add-maven-repo
$ mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: juergen@Kleystation-NB:~/FH/Bakk/jensemble$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/uk/ac/roslin/jensembl-parent/1.13/jensembl-parent-1.13.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'uk.ac.roslin:jensembl-parent:pom:1.13' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).

Comment: Go into the sub folder `jensembl-parent` and run `mvn install` first

Comment: A friend of mine was able to, but I dont know how. He exported the files for me and now it runs like a charm. Sadly no solution from here did work for me. But thanks for your request.

Answer (score 0):

You can import as a maven project  and I feel that is the better way also

I have gone thru the repo you mentioned.

In Eclipse

1. File--> Import --> Check out Maven Projects from SCM

select svn and use this url

```
http://jensembl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jensembl/trunk/
```

or any subdirectory which contains the pom.xml

and see you can proceed further

Comment: Where do you select SVN? I'm not able to, see this link: http://oi46.tinypic.com/2hpqczs.jpg

Comment: In the second Window after selecting  Check out Maven Projects from SCM  where we can see a drop down you can select svn and next is the text box where you can type the SVN url mentioned above. I think this is introduced in eclipse recently. I use Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 0):

On your harddisk a package is a normal folder. If you have the project in eclipse it has to know which of the folders are source folders. Eclipse will show all folders in a source folder as packages and recognize the classed as part of the project. Open the properties of the project. At first you have to go to the category `Project Facets` and enable Java. After that you can go to the category `Java Build Path` and add all source folders in the `Source` tab.

Furthermore you checked out the whole SVN repository which seems to contain a few projects/modules. You want to check them out (or at least import them to Eclipse) seperatly from the [trunk folder](https://jensembl.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jensembl/trunk/). I'm also seeing that your project is a maven project so you might want to read up on maven and how to check out projects in eclipse. Here is a short [how-to](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/11/19/check-out-a-maven-project-from-svn-in-eclipse/). Again you only want the trunk folder. If you want to know what that is you can read it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698313/what-is-trunk-branch-and-tag-in-subversion).