# Branch, Tag, Trunk in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do “branch”, “tag” and “trunk” mean in Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-mean-in-subversion-repositories)

I have been reading about SVN controls but I couldn't find a proper answer for my questions. Please try to be simple when you answer because I don't understand the complex answer which are already on Google. If you can please provide me an example so that It's easy to understand. *I hope that not being able to understand something and asking for a simple answer is not a crime*.

1. What's Branch, Tag, Trunk ?
2. Why we should use Branch, Tag, Trunk ?
3. How to use Branch, Tag, Trunk properly ?
4. When to use Branch, Tag, Trunk ?

Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand in the chapter os the SVN book that explains it in great details? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge

Comment: @Dasun Asking for simple answers is fine - but a simple search using your title ( http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Branch%2C+Tag%2C+Trunk+in+SVN )  brings up several useful answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to explain it in a few easy words.

The **trunk** is the main line of development. This is usually the codebase you start with.

A **branch** is a seperate line of development. This is what you do when you use the trunks code for a different purpose, project or whatever, without conflicting the trunks code.

A **Tag** is more like a label, to find something easier in the future.

These features are there to help you managing your codebase, you have to decide yourself when to use what, depending on what your project(s) look like.

Maybe try [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion#Branching_and_tagging) for Apache Subversion, it is not too hard to understand. Or check out [this great SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698313/what-is-trunk-branch-and-tag-in-subversion), which poses a similar question. The best source however is the [manual itself](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html).