# C++20, how to compile with Clang-10 or GCC11

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm aware that C++20 is not fully supported (yet) by the compilers, but I really want to learn modules and other C++20 stuff.
Modules are supported in GCC11 and Clang-8+.
[Compiler Support of C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

I've installed Clang-10 on my Ubuntu, but it still gives me errors:

```
import <iostream>;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello world";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

COMMANDS:

> clang++ -Wall -std=c++2a -stdlib=libc++ -fimplicit-modules
> -fimplicit-module-maps main.cpp -o main
>
> clang++ -Wall -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fimplicit-modules
> -fimplicit-module-maps main.cpp -o main

ERROR: **fatal error: 'iostream' file not found**

Comment: Hi ! What kinds of errors do you get ? How do you compile this ?

Comment: modules support in the compiler and modules support in the standard library are two different things. c++20 doesn't actually provide standard library modules. Microsoft's implementation of standard library modules which may or may not match a future c++ standard is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160#consume-the-c-standard-library-as-modules

Answer (score 4):

Although c++20 adds modules the c++20 standard library doesn't expose any modules.

Microsoft have implemented some standard library modules which may or may not match a future c++ standard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160#consume-c-standard-library-as-modules-experimental. With these your example would be:

```
import std.core;

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello world";
}
```

As far as I can see neither libc++ or libstdc++ have implemented any modules yet.

Answer (score 3):

By default, gcc trunk use c++17, and clang trunk use c++14, so you have to say compiler, that you want to use c++20

If you are compiling your code in terminal by yourself, than add following flag

```
--std=c++20
```

If you compile your code using Cmake, than add following to your CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

And if you compile in some IDE(Codeblocks or Visual studio), than somewhere in compiler settings put supporting c++20

*trunk* means "the main line of development", so this compiler version should be latest officially supported

Comment: "trunc" is spelled "trunk", and it is actually "master" or "main" now that they switched from subversion to git.

Comment: It's actually "trunk", and that word derives from SVN (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698313/what-is-trunk-branch-and-tag-in-subversion)).