# Can I create multiple dlls from one project?

Tags: c#

I have a very large website which was "published" using Visual Studio 2008 to the dev/live server.  As a result, there are no *.aspx.cs files on the live server, just "website.dll" - all good so far.

However, because we're constantly having to add pages to the site this now means that if I'm half way through developing a big part of the site when I'm required to make a small change elsewhere, I can't publish "website.dll" to the live site because it has all my half finished code in there.  How do people deal with this situation?

If I could split the site up into multiple dlls (perhaps based on namespace?) then I could just publish the small part of the site that's changed, leaving the bit I'm still developing on the dev server.

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not the single assembly, but your way of developing.

To cope with this problem I would introduce a source control system (svn, git, ...) in your environment. These allow you to use branches, you could create 2 branches. One for new development and one for bugfixes or small changes.

These can later be merged to create a new release.

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-really-mean) or [here](http://dobrzanski.net/2009/04/03/how-to-manage-trunkbranchestags-in-the-project-while-bug-fixing-and-regular-development/) and in the manuals of Subversion, Git and other source control systems.

Comment: I'd like to make an addition. Use a strategy where you maintain a stable trunk (just bugfix here), branches for projects where you add new stuff, and branches/tags for releases. Reintegrate branches after a project is finished, and reintegrate release branches before you do a new release.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Split your project in several sub-projects and handle them in a solution. Every project will become a seperate DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Use source control. We use subversion with ahnk+tortoise.
[subversion on wikip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software))