# The Subversion Once Over

Tags: php, svn, project-management, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do “branch”, “tag” and “trunk” really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-really-mean)

I am brand new to subversion, so please bear with me. I know that the standard directory structure for a repository are as follows:

```
/branches/
/tags/
/trunk/
```

I'm not sure what each of these directories are for. Could someone:

1. describe the purpose of each directory
2. provide a sample directory structure for project management in a **single-user** environment
3. provide a sample directory structure for project management in a **multi-user** environment
4. provide sample directory structure(s) for a parent project which will contain multiple add-ons, each being their own smaller project

Sorry for the crash list of questions. I will award extra points for good answers.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you read http://svnbook.red-bean.com? If not do so, and then come back with your questions. And to be honest, although I like SVN, I'd recommend looking at a DVCS like mercurial, unless your use case involves big binary files.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - there are lots of reasons to use SVN. Don't just randomly say try out a DVCS.

Comment: I agree. I am relatively comfortable with SVN, as I have all of the tools. I just need to know the standards. :D

Comment: @manojlds Please point out where I "randomly" said such a thing.

Comment: Ypu don't know why he is using SVN in the first place. For all you know, he moved to SVN from Git. SVN is useful due to many reason apart from Binary files, like great sysadmin tool support.

Comment: @ manojlds You are right - I don't know (and neither do you) - which is why I said "I'd recommend looking at a DVCS like mercurial", and not "I'd recommend changing to a DVCS like mercurial instantly".

Comment: That's okay, I understand you are just trying to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look here : [What do "branch", "tag" and "trunk" mean in Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-really-mean)

One additional detail is that all the folders are just same, it is just a convention to have this structure and they do not have special meaning per se. The structure should be the same in single-user or multi-user environment and it is the one in the question generally.

In multi-user environment, sometimes we have `/privatebranches` meaning that it is some sort of spike and is not for general use. Also these may be non standard as in branch of a particular folder within trunk etc.

For multiple add-ons type project:

```
repo   
    project1
        trunk
        branches
        tags
    addon1
        trunk
        branches
        tags
    addon2
        trunk
        branches
        tags
```

Also in that case you can look at using [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) to manages the projects. So they will still have the above structure, but you can make it seem like the add-ons are contained within Project1

Comment: Could you provide a quick example?

Comment: @spryno724 - Have added an example

Comment: totally awesome, manojlds! thanks!