# How to make git svn clone on an SVN tag fetch the complete history?

Tags: git, svn

In SVN tags are just another URL. So when I clone a URL which points to a tag using `git svn clone <url_of_tag>`, I expected it to fetch the complete history of the tag but it does not. A git log after the clone shows,

```
<some_hash> git-svn-id: <tag_url>@12256 eaa63c25-6722-0410-8f96-99d88de8df57
```

`git svn clone <url_of_trunk>` works fine.

How do I clone a tag URL along with the complete history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that a tag, in SVN is *supposed* to be **immutable** (in that you should *not* do any more version in a SVN tag), it is not surprising that the git svn script doesn't find many commit to create when reading the history of the SVN repo under a tag url.
(See [What do “branch”, “tag” and “trunk” really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-really-mean/114384#114384) in SVN)

Comment: Except for the fact that the URL contains the string "tags", there is nothing to say that this is a tag in SVN. Is there a way to force git svn to consider it as just another SVN URL?

Comment: @Chandru: considering the parameters of git svn, there might actually be a way: try mentioning `--trunk=<actually_your_tag_subdir>` and see if that helps.