# Tagging Certain part of a code in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn

I want to know if I can TAG only a desired part of my code or the whole code along with all the files is tagged altogether?

A kind response will be appreciable :)

Thanks

**Edit**

I would like to edit the question a bit:

Assume a scenario - suppose I have tagged the code to prepare a baseline code from where i can move forward. However, later i come to know that i need to fix some pages but not all the pages that have been checked in after the last build. So I would like to separately tag only those pages related to bug fixing with the older tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is details of SVN, please read this

Tag will be a point in time on the trunk or a branch that you wish to preserve. The two main reasons for preservation would be that either this is a major release of the software, whether alpha, beta, RC or RTM, or this is the most stable point of the software before major revisions on the trunk were applied.

[What do "branch", "tag" and "trunk" mean in Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-mean-in-subversion-repositories)