# Must an SVN repo always have trunk and branches directories -- and for a working directory are they optional?

Tags: svn

I worked in projects using svn (by using Tortoise) that never had a "trunk" directory before, and then moved onto using git, and now two companies I worked for use svn... and the word `trunk` came up sometimes.

From the answers in [What do "branch", "tag" and "trunk" mean in Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-mean-in-subversion-repositories) , it seems like trunk is actually just like the "main branch" as in git?  Do all SVN repo always have the trunk and branches directory, while for a working directory, they are optional?  Such as, if we do

```
svn checkout some_svn_path/trunk .
```

then our working directory has no `trunk` directory whatsoever? (without the `.`, then the `trunk` directory will be there, but with the `.`, the `trunk` directory won't be there).  But what if later on, somebody suggests using a "try-new-feature" branch, then what happens?  I saw in the O'Reilly SVN book that they would have a `calc` project, and then the working directory has a `trunk` sub-directory as well as a `branches` sub-directory.

Comment: I guess the O'Reilly SVN book example was broken (or an unintended example how *not* to checkout using SVN). When you correctly check out the trunk (=main branch), you don't have a trunk dir as working directory. Your main question was already answered at the link you provided by yourself, look at the second best answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do "branch", "tag" and "trunk" mean in Subversion repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-mean-in-subversion-repositories)

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.maint.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout

Answer (score 4):

From URLs of @bahrep you have already know, what Subversion (contrary to Mercurial/Git with their pre-existing branches for mainline) **have not any predefined** layout, but **may have any conventional layout** which is result of agreement between developers only.

- In case of pure linear development (none diverged history, none merges) repository may have flat space (root of repo and nothing more)
- Trunk may be named not as "trunk", but using any another name

Your `svn co` really "checkout *some subtree of repository* into *some local folder*" - local folder may be any, repository subtree also can be any. Source of checkout have only one meaning - later operations can't happens for any repository-objects not under "checkouted root"

> But what if later on, somebody suggests using a "try-new-feature" branch, then what happens?

Nothing. You have to switch your WC for the new root (root of this branch) instead of current of create|checkout new WC for this branch