# SVN symbolic links transparent to Linux and Windows

Tags: java, svn, maven

This is how my SVN looks like now

```
SVN
 + trunk
     + src
     + pom.xml
```

and I want to add

```
 + trunk_alternative_pom
     + src -> SVN/trunk/src
     + pom.xml
```

so when I update the project (in Linux or Windows), it will look like both "src" folders are completely unrelated, although behind the scenes (inside SVN) they are the same.

It's important that the original trunk has not a single byte modified. Assume I can't add pom_alternative.xml to trunk and run Maven with a -f argument,

Comment: I would highly recommend that you make branches/alternative_pom, rather than making a top level copy of trunk.  informative read:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16142/505191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) to point `trunk_alternative_pom/src` at `SVN/trunk/src`

If all clients were using a UNIX-like OS (Linux, MacOS, etc.) you could use a symlink, but SVN on Windows doesn't support symlinks (and NTFS only started supporting it with Windows Vista).