# Where are /trunks /branches /tags folders in svn- repo?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Through the tool TortoisenSVN  created the repository folder with structure: 
[image]

Where are /trunks /branches /tags folders in svn- repo? I may have to create them? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where are /trunks /branches /tags folders in svn- repo?

Inside repository. They are **virtual folders**, not physical, and visible (as any other parts of repository-tree) only in SVN-client (if they was created by TSVN or by hand)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create these folders. These are only folders created base on some name conventions for putting your source code, your branches and your tagged sources.

Please read [What do "branch", "tag" and "trunk" mean in Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-mean-in-subversion-repositories)