# Svn project, get clean files

Tags: linux, svn

I am Russian, sorry for the bad english =)
I have source code of game but i don't no how to get clean files because the game was developed with SVN.

list of files root dir game: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqTDi.png

And in other folder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVQ6F.png

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete all the .svn folders. They are containing the version informations.

Comment: Там еще есть папка -trunk, теги и другие (с SVN). В them файлы игры, путь, который они имеют / платформа / Архив / A3DEncoder / багажник / SRC / платформа / инструменты / a3dencoder /, но должен быть / платформа / Архив / A3DEncoder /. и путь сам архив / должны быть инструменты / снова, потому что SVN /.

Comment: Maybe this helps you to understand the svn structure:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-mean-in-subversion-repositories